# Authorization through setRequestHeader

Tags: javascript, authentication

I found this code which makes it possible to authenticate using setRequestheader and Ajax.

```
this.xmlDoc.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Basic ' + Base64.encode("User:Password"));
```

Unfortunatily I have no knowledge of Ajax and Base64 does not seem to be class or method I can reference. Is there an alternative for this Basic encryption? Or a simular encode function I can call from Javascript?

Thank you !

Comment: What kind of request are you trying to authorize?  The code sample you gave adds authorization to an xmlhttprequest, is that what you're doing?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not specifying.
this.xmlDoc=!_isIE&&window.XMLHttpRequest?new XMLHttpRequest:new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

Comment: @user1365889 You could google [javascript base64 encode](http://www.google.com/?q=javascript+base64+encode) which is what all the answers you get will have done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a function to Base64 encode the User:Password string.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-to-base64-using-javascript) which gives a couple of good options to do this in javascript.

Comment: Is there an option of not using any encryption at all?

Comment: Base64 is not an encryption, it's an encoding.  It's used (among other reasons) to reduce the size of the string when you send it over the network.

Comment: @just.another.programmer base64 increases the size of any string by 33%. So that's pretty wrong.

Comment: It's for representing binary data with safe ascii characters